# Storing the API endpoints in a Pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, constants

I am currently trying to create an API-wrapper. For that, I connect to the endpoint (for example https://host.example.com/api/accounts/open) with the request module. Since there are a bunch of endpoints, I need a way to sort them. Currently I have a constants file, where most of the endpoints are created like this:

```
HOST = 'https://wallet.shiftnrg.org'
START = ''.join([HOST, '/api'])

ACCOUNTS = ''.join([START, '/accounts'])
ACCOUNTS_OPEN = ''.join([ACCOUNTS, '/open'])
...
LOADER = ''.join([START, '/loader'])
LOADER_GET_STATUS = ''.join([LOADER, '/status'])
```

And I access them like this (one example):

```
def accounts_get_balance(address):
    payload = {'address': address}

response = requests.get(constants.ACCOUNTS_GET_BALANCE,
                        params=payload,
                        timeout=constants.TIMEOUT
)
```

While this is working, I was wondering if there is a more efficient, pythonic way of doing this, since I am just a beginner (especially the constants.py, but if you find anything else, feel free to tell me as well!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A tip on the second part, is looking to what Brendan Rhodes has to say about [Clean Architecture](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#clean-architecture-python) and bring your IO out as much as possible. This will make testing everything a lot easier, and limit the number of God-methods that do everything from constructing the query, getting the response to parsing and persisting the result

For the first part, I would work with a `dict` of destinations, that you can persist via `json` or so

```
settings = {
    'host': 'https://wallet.shiftnrg.org',
    'entry-points':{
        'start': ('api',),
        'accounts': ('_start', 'accounts'),
        'accounts_open': ('_accounts', 'open'),
        'loader': ('_start', 'loader')
    }

}
```

that you can dump to and load from `json`

For the entry-points, I would parse this somewhat like this:

```
def parse_entry_points(entry_points):
    for name, path in entry_points.items():
        yield name, list(expand_path(entry_points, name))

def expand_path(entry_points, item):
    path = entry_points[item]
    for item in path:
        if item[0] != '_':
            yield item
        else:
            yield from expand_path(entry_points, item[1:])

ENTRY_POINTS = dict(parse_entry_points(entry_points=settings['entry-points']))
```

Off course you can/should replace the `_`-placeholder with a unicode symbol that will not figure in the eventual URLs

> ```
> {'accounts': ['api', 'accounts'],
>  'accounts_open': ['api', 'accounts', 'open'],
>  'loader': ['api', 'loader'],
>  'start': ['api']}
> ```

assembling the URL can then be as simple as

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
def assemble_url(enty_point):
    parts = constants.ENTRY_POINTS[entry_point]
    return urljoin(constants.HOST, parts)
```

Answer (score 6):

If the API routes are consistent, I'd suggest making use of [the `__getattr__` metamethod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295743/1190388).

A simple example would be

```
class APIRoutes:
    _BASE = "https://wallet.shiftnrg.org/"
    _BASE_API = _BASE + "api/"
    def __getattr__(self, route):
        return self._BASE_API + route.lower().replace('_', '/')
```

Now, in your code:

```
api_routes = APIRoutes()
.
.
...
def accounts_get_balance(address):
    payload = {'address': address}
    response = requests.get(api_routes.ACCOUNTS_GET_BALANCE,
                        params=payload,
                        timeout=constants.TIMEOUT
)
```

where `api_routes.ACCOUNTS_GET_BALANCE` will generate

```
https://wallet.shiftnrg.org/api/accounts/get/balance
```

---

If for eg. you think that writing `api_routes.A_B_C_D_E` is too cumbersome for a specific path, you can override that in the class itself to a shorter version.

```
class APIRoutes:
    _BASE = "https://wallet.shiftnrg.org/"
    _BASE_API = _BASE + "api/"
    SHORT = _BASE_API + "/some/long/route/for/api"
    def __getattr__(self, route):
        return self._BASE_API + route.lower().replace('_', '/')
```

Comment: Could you clarify how I would override that in the class to a shorter version?

Comment: @strontiux updated